# Cordova Https ajax requests fails or encoded response

Tags: ajax, cordova, ssl, https, websphere

We have developed an application which is running perfectly fine on desktop and mobile web with verisign certificate (https). We have developed iOS and android cordova application which was working fine with http server. For production they have enabled SSL. The iOS and android hybrid applications are not working fine because of ajax call response. The following response I am receiving for both http and https. Is there any changes required in client side or its all about SSL? Is there any workaround for SSL decoded response? We are using IBM's websphere application server.

Response from http server
    `[{"SALT":"3FzekTIywrmm9jojnfHn11"}]`

Response from https server

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1"></head><body>
    <script type=text/javascript>
     function decode_base64(input){
       var keyStr="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";var output="";
       var chr1,chr2,chr3;var enc1,enc2,enc3,enc4;var i=0;input=input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");
       while(i<input.length){
         enc1=keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
         enc2=keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
         enc3=keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
         enc4=keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
         chr1=(enc1<<2)|(enc2>>4);
         chr2=((enc2&15)<<4)|(enc3>>2);
         chr3=((enc3&3)<<6)|enc4;output=output+String.fromCharCode(chr1);if(enc3!=64){
         output=output+String.fromCharCode(chr2)
       }
       if(enc4!=64){
         output=output+String.fromCharCode(chr3)}}return output;
       }      
       document.write(decode_base64("PHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPXRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdD52YXIgdG9fZGVjPWRlY29kZV9iYXNlNjQoImNtUjFWV2hzWkc1MGRTbG5kRzlpZFdodWJ5RXBLSG9oWlc1aWRHeGtiM1V2Ylc1aVlIVm9ibTg4SXk0eGUzRnZMaU02SVh3dElUQXhNVEVvIik7IGRlY19yZXM9IiI7IHZhciB4b3Jfa2V5PTE7IGZvcihpPTA7aTw2MDtpKyspeyBkZWNfcmVzKz1TdHJpbmcuZnJvbUNoYXJDb2RlKHhvcl9rZXledG9fZGVjLmNoYXJDb2RlQXQoaSkpO30gZXZhbChkZWNfcmVzKTs8L3NjcmlwdD4="));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is quite odd way to return the error message, but your HTTPS server is telling

```
i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph"
```

You can see that by

1. copy-paste the HTML to text editor,
2. Name it like *foo.html*,
3. Open it on browser,
4. Open developer tools and see console where it says that.

To answer your question: from point of view of client-side coding there isn't really much difference between HTTP and HTTPS calls. Browser tends to hide those quite effectively, though the performance is in general weaker on HTTPS calls etc.

Comment: Thanks Sanfor, I am not receiving any logs as you said, I tried adding request header for "Content-Language" - "es" still same in response. Is there any workaround in server side to get the proper json response or client side to make it work?

Comment: @Senthil: As that is an answer from your server and it works with HTTP, I would take a look at the server to see if any error exist in log there.